# Generalization of the Hermite-Bielher-Kakeya Theorem

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, polynomials

A stable polynomial is one with zeros in the upper half plane or lower half plane. Interlacing polynomials are polynomials with only real zeros, where between every two zeros of one polynomial lies a zero of the other polynomial, in the sense that they can be ordered from least to greatest. Two interlacing polynomials automatically must be within a degree of each other. We now state two important theorems, (see Rahman & Schmeisser, page 197-199).

Hermite-Bielher - Given two real-valued polynomials, $f$ and $g$, then $f(x)+g(x) w$ is stable for every $w\in\mathbb{C}$, if and only if, $f$ and $g$ have real interlacing zeros.

Hermite-Kakeya - Given two real-valued polynomials, $f$ and $g$, then $f(x)+g(x) r$ has only real zeros for every $r\in\mathbb{R}$, if and only if, $f$ and $g$ have real interlacing zeros.

Hence, we put these theorems together,

Hermite-Bielher-Kakeya - Given two real-valued polynomials, $f$ and $g$, then $f(x)+g(x)w$ is stable for every $w\in\mathbb{C}$, if and only if, $f(x)+g(x) r$ has only real zeros for every $r\in\mathbb{R}$.

I think this generalizes, but I am struggling with finding a proof.

**Hermite-Bielher-Kakeya (Generalization) - Given real-valued polynomials, $\{f_k\}_{k=0}^n$ (needs an added condition about the leading coefficients), then $\sum_{k=0}^n f_k(x)w^k$ is stable for every $w\in\mathbb{C}$, if and only if, $\sum_{k=0}^n f_k(x) r^k$ has only real zeros for every $r\in\mathbb{R}$.**

One direction is obvious, since it is a weaker condition. I am interested in the other direction. Let's simplify the statement to the simplest case possible.

Hermite-Bielher-Kakeya (Generalization) (Small Case) - Given three real-valued polynomials with positive leading coefficients, a quadratic, $Q_2(x)$, a linear, $Q_1(x)$, and a constant, $Q_0(x)$, then $Q_2(x)w^2+Q_1(x)w+Q_0(x)$ is stable for every $w\in\mathbb{C}$, if and only if, $Q_2(x)r^2+Q_1(x)r+Q_0(x)$ has only real zeros for every $r\in\mathbb{R}$.

1) I already have a tedious "working proof" (14 pages with geometric pictures and some operator theory) of the special case. It doesn't seem it should be that difficult. Is there a simple proof of the special case?

2) Is there a proof (or counterexample) of the generalized case?

Comment: See the work of P Brändén and (late) J Borcea. They have a lot of results regarding stability, if you are not already familiar with their works.

Comment: Oh, yes, I read their incredible work all the time. :-)

Answer (score 3):

This would be a nice extension of the Hermite-Biehler theorem, but I think that it is not true, even in the special case. Choose $Q_2(x)=1-x^2$, $Q_1(x)=2x+1$, and $Q_2(x)=1$. Then
$$
Q_2(x)r^2 + Q_1(x)r+Q_0(x)=-r^2x^2+2rx+r^2+r+1
$$
has the discriminant
$$
4r^2(r^2+r+2)
$$
which is positive for all $r\in\mathbb{R}$. However, Wolfram Alpha says that
$$
4((i/2)^2Q_2(x) + i/2\, Q_1(x) + Q_0(x)) = x^2 + 4ix + 3 + 2i
$$
is not stable. For a non-numerical argument observe that if
$$
F(x,w) = Q_2(x)w^2 + Q_1(x)w+Q_0(x)
$$
is stable for all $w\in\mathbb{C}$, then by the Hermite-Biehler theorem $\Re F(x,w)$ and $\Im F(x,w)$ have interlacing zeros - and thus in particular only real zeros - for all $w\in\mathbb{C}$. But $\Re F(x,ib)=0$, $b\in\mathbb{R}$, is equivalent to
$$
1-x^2 = \frac{1}{b^2},
$$
and this equation has no real solutions when $|b|<1$.

Comment: Thank you for the response and what a most excellent example. Meaning I completely forgot the assumption that the $Q_k$ are to have leading coefficients that are positive (or negative) (or alternating). You leading coefficients follow, + + - which won't work.

Comment: Updated the question to reflect the coefficient condition.

Comment: If interested, I ask a slightly weaker question as a follow up here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/168581/generalization-of-the-hermite-beihler-kakeya-theorem-2 Proving the weaker statement wouldn't prove the above, but it would be a start.